# Connecting vertices with more than one attribute

Tags: r, igraph

I want to generate a sociogram. Therefore, I want to connect likes and dislikes in one plot.
It is possible, that there are no likes/dislikes from/for some persons.
Data.csv

```
Name;Like;Dislike
Jeff;Cathrine;George
Anna;Simone;
George;Cathrine;
Henry;Mike;
Cathrine;Henry;
Simone;Jeff;Joe
Joe;Jeff;
Judy;Mike;
Mike;Cathrine;Anna
```

That's what I have tried for now but the problem is that the names/vertices of the likes are not connected to the dislikes. So in the generated plot the names/vertices are not connected correctly. Have you got any idea to solve this?
Thanks
Stefan

```
library(igraph)

data <- read.csv2("Data.csv", header=TRUE, na.strings = "")

Elike <- data[, 1:2]
Edislike <- like[, c(1, 3)]
glike <- graph.data.frame(Elike, directed=TRUE)
gdislike<- graph.data.frame(Edislike, directed=TRUE)

for(i in 1:nrow(Data)){
  ifelse(is.na(Edislike$Dislike[i]), Edislike$Dislike[i]<-Edislike$Name[i], Edislike$Dislike[i]<-Edislike$Dislike[i])
}
gabwahl <- simplify( gabwahl, remove.loops = TRUE)

E(glike)$curved <- 0.5
E(gdislike)$curved <- -0.1
E(glike)$color <- "green"
E(gdislike)$color <- "red"
E(glike)$arrow.size <- 0.1
E(gdislike)$arrow.size <- 0.1


V(glike)$shape <- "none"
V(gdislike)$shape <- "none"
V(glike)$label <- V(glike)$name
V(gdislike)$label <- V(gdislike)$name

plot(glike, layout=layout.circle)
plot(gdislike, layout=layout.circle, add = TRUE)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You should melt your data frame and read it into `igraph` with `graph_from_data_frame`, which will automatically assign edge attributes using the third column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)
library(reshape2)

dat <- read.delim(textConnection("Name;Like;Dislike
Jeff;Cathrine;George
Anna;Simone;
George;Cathrine;
Henry;Mike;
Cathrine;Henry;
Simone;Jeff;Joe
Joe;Jeff;
Judy;Mike;
Mike;Cathrine;Anna"), sep = ";",
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
library(tidygraph)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

melt_dat <- reshape2::melt(dat, 
                           id.vars = "Name") %>% 
  select(Name, value, variable) %>% #need to switch the second and third columns so that likes/dislikes are in the 3rd column
  filter(value != "") %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame()


ggraph(melt_dat) + 
  geom_node_point() +
  geom_edge_link(aes(color = variable))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this idea! For what I understand I am not able to create the vertices and edges with V() and E() than, am I?

Comment: `V()` and `E()` access vertices and edges sequences respectively. If you want to create vertices and edge--that is, if you want to add them to a graph--you use `add_vertices` and `add_edges`. So let's say you had another person--Molly--with no likes or dislikes: `g <- g %>% add_vertices(1, name = "Molly")`. Adds vertex info, but no edge info.

Comment: Hi paqmo, thanks again for your answer. I will always read csv-files so I won't have to add vertices manually. I', just not so familiar with ggplot. I think I have to change that. ;) I tweaked your code so that instead of only points the vertices will be displayed with the names of the people. What I recognized for now is that some names occure several times (eg Simone) but that's not who a sociogram works, they should only appear once. I tried to understand the melt() of data but I'm not sure how to fix this issue. <img src="https://imgur.com/a/E3gtE" width="200" height="100">

Comment: 'ggraph(melt_dat) + 
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name))  +
  geom_edge_link(aes(color = variable))'